# Bulk convert log file date time format from 12 hour clock to 24 hour clock for mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, bulk-load

I am creating a web app to analyze data from a client's custom database.  I am having difficulty finding a way how to convert the client's log file entries from 12 hour clock to 24 hour clock.  The Database that I am setting this up with cannot read 12 hour time format, so is displaying the time wrong.

Log files I am using look like this:

```
Site_Name,number_of_clicks,DD/MM/YYYY_2:00PM,Interaction_Type
```

I need to convert the log files to look like this:

```
Site_Name,number_of_clicks,DD/MM/YYYY_14:00,Interaction_Type
```

There are tens of thousands of enteries per log file, so there is no way this can be done per entry.  I need to figure out a way to bulk convert the entries to 24-hour clock for each of the log files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Aaron

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server?

Comment: I have tried nothing as of yet.  Log files are being to delivered to us from ms sql server (client's DB), and our DB is running on mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that on db side and you use MySql you can read it with `STR_TO_DATE()` and either use it as a datetime value

```sql
INSERT INTO log (`Site_Name`, `number_of_clicks`, `date`, `Interaction_Type`)
SELECT 'site1', 10, STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2013_2:00PM', '%d/%m/%Y_%l:%i%p'), 1;
```

or

```sql
UPDATE log
   SET date = STR_TO_DATE(str_date, '%d/%m/%Y_%l:%i%p');
```

assuming that `date` column is of type datetime, and `str_date` column contains string values in 12h format.

or if for  some reason you store it as `VARCHAR` and really need to format it as `DD/MM/YYYY_14:00` then you can use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2013_2:00PM', '%d/%m/%Y_%l:%i%p'), '%d/%m/%Y_%k:%i')
```

which will produce

```
|          NEWDATE |
--------------------
| 10/05/2013_14:00 |
```

To update in-place

```
UPDATE log
   SET str_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(str_date, '%d/%m/%Y_%l:%i%p'), '%d/%m/%Y_%k:%i');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54891/3)** demo.

Comment: Thank you! I will try with that and post the results

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you write a simple app that will search through all log entries and update whenever it finds date in PM format.
You basically need to write a piece of code that will add 12 hrs if there is PM in the time.

Here is a rough code in C#... not fully tested but you can build on this…

```
protected string ConvertToPM(string logEntry)

{
    string result = string.Empty;

//DD/MM/YYYY_2:00PM
if (logEntry.Contains("PM"))
{
   string temp = logEntry.Substring(logEntry.IndexOf("_"), logEntry.IndexOf(":") - logEntry.IndexOf("_"));

    result = logEntry.Replace(temp, (Convert.ToInt32(temp) + 12).ToString());
}

return result;
}
```

Just add a piece of code that will a) read log file line by line b) extract date part c) use function similar to the one above to alter the data…